# Как правильно склеить две строки в Си?

Tags: c

При исполнении кода

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *first = "first";
    char *second = "second";
    char *third = strcat(first, second);
}
```

происходит ошибка сегментирования.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что функция strcat не выделяет память, а копирует из одной строки в другую. Поскольку длина первой строки меньше, чем длина второй, то память перетирается. Нужно изменить код, например, так.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char first[7] = "first";
    char second[7] = "second";
    char *third = strcat(first, second);
}
```

Comment: Ваш код осуществляет попытку записи за пределами выделенной памяти. Это UB.

Answer (score 10):

Если содержимое строк известно на этапе компиляции, то и склеивание можно организовать на этапе компиляции

```
#define FIRST  "first"
#define SECOND "second"

int main(void) 
{
    const char *first  = FIRST;
    const char *second = SECOND;
    const char *third  = FIRST SECOND;
}
```

Но это уж зависит от того, что именно вам нужно.

Для склеивания во время выполнения использовать функцию `strcat` - не самая лучшая идея из-за того, что при каждом склеивании функция снова и снова выполняет сканирование уже построенной части строки. (По этой причине `strcat` - фактически бесполезная функция.) Лучше уж воспользоваться для этих целей обычным `snprintf`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char *first  = "first";
    const char *second = "second";

    char third[512];
    snprintf(third, sizeof third, "%s%s", first, second);
}
```

А уж какой способ резервирования памяти для строки-получателя вам больше подходит - зависит от ваших конкретных обстоятельств и требований.

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы склеить 2 строки в Си, нужно выполнить следующие действия:

1. При помощи функции `malloc` выделить блок памяти (`result`), достаточный для сохранения в него обеих строк (и не забыть про место, для завершающего нуля)
2. При помощи функции `memcpy` скопировать первую строку `s1` в начало выделенного блока
3. При помощи всё той же функции `memcpy` скопировать вторую строку `s2`, вместе с её нулём, в выделенный блок, со смещением на размер первой строки
4. После того, как вы совершили какие-то манипуляции с полученной строкой, её нужно освободить, при помощи функции `free`

Пример:

```
    char* concat(char *s1, char *s2) {

        size_t len1 = strlen(s1);
        size_t len2 = strlen(s2);                      

        char *result = malloc(len1 + len2 + 1);

        if (!result) {
            fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed: insufficient memory!\n");
            return NULL;
        }

        memcpy(result, s1, len1);
        memcpy(result + len1, s2, len2 + 1);    

        return result;
    }
```

Как использовать:

```
    char *s = concat("first", "second");
    printf("%s\n", s);
    free(s);
```

Comment: Зачем всё это? Надо просто правильно пользоваться `strcat`.

Comment: @alexolut затем, что `memcpy` не совершает лишних действий и работает быстрее, чем `strcat`.

Comment: Если Вас смущает определение длины первой строки каждый раз, так передавайте сразу указатель на терминирующий ноль в `strcat`, и лишних расходов не будет.

Comment: Ок, тоже вариант. Но мне вариант с `memcpy` всё равно больше нравится.

Answer (score 3):

Для `strcat` первый аргумент должен указывать на буфер достаточной длины, чтобы в него могла поместиться итоговая (склеенная) строка. Переменные `first` и `second` являются указателями на строковые литералы, т.е. данные по таким указателям изменять нельзя. Это приводит к неопределенному поведению (UB).

Исходный пример может быть переписан следующим образом:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const char* first = "first"; // const явно указывает, что такие данные менять нельзя
    const char* second = "second";
    char* buff = calloc(strlen(first) + strlen(second) + 1, 1);
    strcat(buff, first);
    strcat(buff, second);
    printf("%s\n", buff);
    free(buff);
}
```

<kbd>[Результат выполнения](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/iyUUGc7Iq5E0okFk)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант - явно зарезервировать под первую строку (к которой будет "приклеиваться" вторая строка) памяти с запасом:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char first[256] = "first";
    char second[] = "second";
    strcat(first, second);
    puts(first);
    return 0;
}
```

Результат выполнения: http://ideone.com/OOXUCV

Answer (score 1):

Раз уж пошло такое массовое отвечание некропоста, то внесу и свою лепту.

В GNU есть очень удобный аналог `sprintf` -- [asprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf), которая размещает результат "вывода" своих аргументов в динамической памяти (использует malloc).

Соответственно, программа может быть такой:

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char first[] = "first", 
    second[] = "second";
  char *third;

  if (asprintf(&third, "%s%s", first, second) < 0)
    third = strdup(strerror(errno));

  return puts(third) == EOF;
}
```

А если у вас ее (asprintf) нет, то несложно и самому написать

```
static int 
asprintf (char **ps, const char *fmt, ...)
{
  //   puts("my asprintf");
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, fmt);
  int rc = vsnprintf(*ps, 0, fmt, ap);
  va_end(ap);
  if (rc >= 0) {
    if ((*ps = (char *)malloc(rc + 2))) {
      va_start(ap, fmt);
      rc = vsnprintf(*ps, rc + 1, fmt, ap);
      va_end(ap);
    } else
      rc = -1;
  }

  return rc;
}
```

(или скопипастить) и использовать уже без всяких `#define _GNU_SOURCE` даже в винде (по крайней мере MinGW успешно транслирует).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* concat(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    char *result = malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);//+1 нужен для нуль-терминатора строки.
    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, s2);
    return result;
}
```

1. Выделяем нужное количество памяти
2. Склеиваем и возвращаем указатель на начало блока памяти.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что функция `strcat()` добавляет

- строку, на которую указывает *второй* параметр (`"second"`)
- к строке, на которую указывает *первый* параметр (`"first"`)
- и затем вращает *первый* параметр - указатель на *первую* строку, **но к которой теперь добавлена и вторая строка**,

нужно для *первого* параметра выделить достаточную память для соединенной строки (`"firstsecond"`) - или во время компиляции, или динамически.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void myStrcat(char* des, char* src);
int main () {
  char des[100];
  char cat[50];

  printf("Введите строку 1:");
  fgets(des, 100, stdin);
  des[strlen(des)-1] = '\0';
  printf("Введите строку 2:");
  fgets(cat, 50, stdin);

  cat[strlen(cat)-1] = '\0';
  myStrcat(des, cat);

  printf("%s\n", des);

  getchar();
  return 0;
}

void myStrcat(char *des, char *src)
{
  int len1 = strlen(des);
  int len2 = strlen(src);                      

  memcpy(des + len1, src, len2 + 1);    

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]